# How to maintain a PHP object through successives AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, serial-port

I am programming a php page for controlling a serial port using some in-screen-buttons. When I press a button, this sends some data through the serial port and it shows its response. All this is working OK.

Now, I need to listen continuously the serial port in order to receive data that I haven't ask for. I'm trying to do it with a timer in javascript, but every time I execute the PHP code through AJAX, serial port is restarted and its buffer is flushed. I need to pass the object that controls the serial port to the javascript code before finish the execution of the PHP code. And when pressing a button, I need to pass this object to the new PHP code.

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I've forgotten to say that I need to pass the object by reference in order to get access to the serial port without flush the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that this is imposible to be done: when the PHP code finish its execution, the serial port is closed automatically, so I lost all the data received untill I open the port again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php
You should pass the serialized object or, to keep the Serial Object alive between sessions, store it in a text file. On the `AJAX` end, store it as a `Global [WINDOW] variable`. Such as

```
window.serialphpobject = data;
```

then on the next AJAX call use this data

```
{object: window.serialphpobject}
```

All for example obviously, without seeing your code I cannot fit it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

First create a global js variable in your code.
When you first make ajax call then store response in your js variable.

so everytime you need to pass that global js variable through ajax.

You can make window level js global variable using

```
window.myVariable="";
```

make sure to define this variable before sending any js request

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pass the object that controls the serial port to the javascript code before finish the execution of the PHP code. And when pressing a button, I need to pass this object to the new PHP code.

This solution would be vulnerable. You should keep the information in a PHP session.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php